# Table columns size not working with col-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, core-ui

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-5">Name</th>
                <th class="col-3">Login</th>
                <th class="col-3">Role</th>
                <th class="col-1"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>Juliano</td>
                <td>juliano</td>
                <td>Supervisor</td>
                <td>
                  <a class="float-right holder-icon-link" href="null"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
                  <a class="float-right holder-icon-link" ng-reflect-router-link="/users/edit,4" href="#/users/edit/4"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

However the columns are not respecting the sizes I've set on each `<th></th>`. The first column is taking almost all of the available space and the others are using just the space necessary for its content.

Why?

PS: I'm using [CoreUI's](http://www.coreui.io) template.

Comment: The grid system classes in Bootstrap 4 are meant to be used within `container` and `row` divs, not inside table elements. If using a table is really necessary, you can use percentage widths for your `th` elements or make use of the responsive table utilities in Bootstrap 4 (horizontal scroll though).